# How do you access a Sequelize instance in a VueJS component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron, sequelize.js

I've an Electron/Vue app built with electron-vue, but I can't work out how to access a Sequelize instance which is initialised in main.js, in the component `.vue` files.

The `src/renderer/main.js` file contains the usual imports:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize'
import mysql2 from 'mysql2'

// create sequelize instance as normal
let db = new Sequelize(
  'database', 'user', 'password', {
    host: '1.2.3.4',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectModule: mysql2
})

new Vue({
  components: { App },
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App/>'
}).$mount('#app')
```

Now in a `src/renderer/components/Settings.vue` file I'd like to be able to make a database call, for example:

```
<template>
...
  <button @click="testDatabaseConnection()">Test Database</button>
...
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Settings',
    methods: {
        navigate(route) {
            this.$router.push(route);
        },

        testDatabaseConnection() {
            // access the Sequelize instance
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Am I doing this in the right/wrong place?  How would you put the `db` variable into a scope that the Vue component can access?  Are there any best practices here that I should read up on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `import` Javascript files/vars/objects by using the `import` keyword in the component .vue file.

For example:

**Settings.vue**

```
<template>
 ...
</template>

<script>
import db from '../../database/connection'

export default {
    name: 'Settings',
    methods: {
        async testDbConnection() {
            // Can access the db object from the import statement
            let result = await db.sequelize.query(...)
        },

</script>
```